# How to overlay widget on widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, overlay

I'd need to build a content widget with the red circle over the text content in Flutter, how can I do? [image]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so that we can be able to get your concept

Comment: I had to add the snipped code here for the widget https://codeshare.io/j0EJM3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using `stack` widget

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 450,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Container(
                  width: 400,
                  height: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(20)
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Try to edit this code https://codeshare.io/j0EJM3